# Outlook subject line limit

Tags: excel, outlook

I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

My workplace uses an email to text system where we can send an email which contains the phone number recipients in the subject line.

I've got a simple excel spreadsheet which allows us to send out one email to a populated list of phone numbers.

The problem I am encountering is that the recipient list has grown and now exceeds the 256 character limit in outlooks subject line field.

Is there anyway to workaround this limitation without splitting the contact list?

This is what i am using now:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "text system"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Sheets("Contact").Range("M2:M2")
    .HTMLBody = Sheets("SMSTemplate").Range("A1:A1") & "endsms"
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have used TEXTJOIN on M2 to populate that cell.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think you can get around the limit though. You can nest this inside a loop though to get the same job done. What is the format of the numbers? And is the format consistent? Also, how are the numbers separated in the subject line? Comma separated?

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. yep its consistent 10 numerical characters separated by a semi colon and a space

Comment: This is an XY problem. Instead of figuring out how to exceed the subject limit, you should be asking about a better way to do this that doesn't use the subject line.

Comment: Is this all in one cell on your sheet? How are the number formatted?

Comment: @KenWhite if this is anything like some of the automation my company has internally, it's built to work off the subject line. Clearly a limitation on that automation but it's something used company wide to get messages directly to phone in emergencies. In that context, I think you will need to loop to send batches rather all at once - unless you can switch to sending these directly to email rather phone

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much control of how the implementation works, with regards to using anything other than the subject field.  I used text join to put all the data in one cell but they are stored in a column on the original sheet.  So we are thinking do a loop of 20 numbers to keep it under the line limit? Is there a way to automatically start another outgoing email every 20 rows or something?

Comment: @urdearboy: That's not going to change the 256-character limit in Outlook subject lines, though. I've developed systems that do emergency notifications to a large number of employees via text and/or email, and have never had the need to use the subject line of an email to pass a list of those numbers. And Outlook won't allow you to exceed 256 characters - there's no workaround for that limitation using the subject line.

Comment: @KenWhite - agree it's not a well thought out system but rarely does a random employee get to change a company tool, especially on short notice.. i.e. sometimes you have to work with the limitations in place. **There is a workaround** which is to send the message in batches inside a loop

Answer (score 0):

The [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) in section 2.1.1 states the following:

> There are two limits that this
>   standard places on the number of
>   characters in a line. Each line of
>   characters MUST be no more than 998
>   characters, and SHOULD be no more than
>   78 characters, excluding the CRLF.

As the RFC states later, you can work around this limit (not that you should) by folding the subject over multiple lines.

> Each header field is logically a
>   single line of characters comprising
>   the field name, the colon, and the
>   field body.  For convenience however,
>   and to deal with the 998/78 character
>   limitations per line, the field body
>   portion of a header field can be split
>   into a multiple line representation;
>   this is called "folding".  The general
>   rule is that wherever this standard
>   allows for folding white space (not
>   simply WSP characters), a CRLF may be
>   inserted before any WSP.  For 
>   example, the header field:
>
> ```
>        Subject: This is a test
> ```
>
> can be represented as:
>
> ```
>        Subject: This
>         is a test
> ```

The recommendation for no more than 78 characters in the subject header sounds reasonable.

As a workaround, you may consider adding your long stories to the message body.